# Автоматическое сохранение файла CSS при компиляции из файла SCSS в VS CODE

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, scss, sftp

Использую редактор кода Visual studio code. Для написания scss использую расширение Live Sass Compiler, а для соединения с хостингом использую SFTP. При написании scss локально, всё отрабатывает отлично: расширение Live Sass Compiler на лету компилирует код файла .scss в файл .css.
Сейчас решил попробовать писать scss прямо на сервере, посредством подключения с помощью расширения SFTP. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при сохранении файла .scss, происходит компиляция в файл .css и автоматическое обновление содержимого файла .scss на сервере. А вот файл .css принимает скомпилированный код, но изменения автоматически на сервер не заливаются. Такая же ситуация с файлом карты .css.map. Приходится сохранять 3 файла вручную: .scss, .css, .css.map.

Можно ли, каким-нибудь образом настроить так, чтобы при сохранении файла .scss, происходило автоматическое обновление содержимых файлов .css и .css.map на сервере.
И да, я знаю что у VS Code есть настройки автосохранения файлов. Данную проблему это не решает, т.к. автосохранение происходит только если изменения в данном файле осуществлялись вручную, а не посредством получения данных из другого файла при изменении.
Знаю что можно настроить сборщики на проекте, но интересует, можно ли решить проблему без оных.

Answer (score 0):

sftp

"watcher": {
"files": "path/to/css/*",
"autoUpload": true,
"autoDelete": true
}

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]